# PLSQL encountered the symbol "end-offile"... PLS-00103

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, pls-00103

I'm quite new at PL SQL, when I tried to write sth like below:

```
BEGIN FOR foo IN (SELECT A, B, C FROM foo_table WHERE some_conditions) LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sth here')
END LOOP;
```

I got following error while executing statment in SQL Developer

Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting is one the following:
begin case declare end exception and more...

What's wrong with my statement? Could anyone give me a tip how to resolve this? I'll be very glad for all hints.

Comment: PL/SQL uses semi-colon (;) line endings... if that is your actual code start there: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/controlstructures.htm

Comment: ooops, i forgot about it in my example, In origin code it's END LOOP; and the error is like I wrote in my first post.

updated, but I got the error when semicolon already was placed in my code.

Answer (score 9):

As well as missing the `;` an `end;` is missing too. This code should work:

```
BEGIN FOR foo IN (SELECT A, B, C FROM foo_table WHERE some_conditions) LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('sth here');
END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `end` keyword to close off the `begin`.

This kind of thing tends to jump out at you when you format your code.

```
begin
    for foo in (
        select a, b, c from foo_table where some_conditions
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line('sth here');
    end loop;
```

(Edit: somehow I missed John's correct reply before posting.)